# A word/phrase to describe a person who attends vocational school to become a house painter/decorator

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, british-english

I am wondering how I could say this with just one or a few words, but I cannot seem to be able to find a correct sounding way of saying it. House painting student? House painter in training? Soon-to-be house painter? It all sounds very stiff and clunky, and so far google has been of no help.

I would use it in a short introduction of myself, one that is formatted similarly to "30. Male. Applied biologist. Artist.", so it does not need to be formal at all. The course I am attending is not an apprenticeship, so I am guessing calling myself an apprentice would be incorrect, too.

Comment: Trainee decorator would sound most natural to me.

Comment: @Cascabel Europe! I'm sorry if this is a repeat question, I tried to look for one but couldn't find any that answered my question.

Comment: I added the tag for British English. If you want something different you can edit to add the tag.

Comment: I found a post about [American equivalent for BrE decorator/painter.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314854/ameng-equivalent-for-breng-decorator), but it does not address the issue of trainee.